# How much money do you need to open every fairy fountain?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

The fairy fountains seem to cost more and more, the more you open them.

How much do they cost each?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first Fairy Fountain will cost 100 rupees, the second 500, the third 1,000, and the fourth will cost you 10,000 rupees.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @Yuuki's answer, there is a fifth Fairy Fountain which costs 1 000 rupees to open.

That fountain looks just like the other 4 fountains, but is quite special indeed.

> It is found at *Malanya's Spring* near the *Lake of the Horse God* which is just behind the *Highland Stable*. Its purpose is to revive any horse you have registered that has died during your adventure.

Answer (score -2):

11600 Rupees

I recommend Farosh farming or Pondo's Lodge as the grinding methods.

Comment: The question seems to be asking specific costs for each Fountain.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Hope you have fun here, but here's a tip: If the question has already been answered, except if you have something big to add, there is no need to re-answer the question. Your farming spots could have simply been a comment on Yuuki's answer above.